# Why were so many Tezos burned in this transaction?

Tags: transactions, fees, burn

Is most of the fee coming from the storage? Or How can I know what % of the 6.49Tz burn came from what?

Any suggestions on how can I could make this more efficient?

https://better-call.dev/edo2net/opg/opC3URYwFveQfKPzjWj1yhuYfCokGxHFhCfFCyEUr9XGmjm7dmd/contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason is the storage diff resulted from the transaction.

[image: matrix diff]

Adding 380 items to a big map at once is very expensive.

For your use case, storing the corner coordinates should be enough.

Comment: is 90%+ of the fee on the storage itself rather than the computations needed to perform the storage? Just curious to know if it's possible to know how how much of the fee was spent on computations rather than storage...

Comment: Fee <> Burn. Burn cost can be "estimated" by multiplying the number of storage bytes by "cost_per_byte" constant.